# What classes don't originate from Node, and how are they incorperated into the code lifecycle?

Tags: class, nodes, lifecycle, godot

Was watching a lesson about Godot and the lifecycle of code. It was mentioned in the lesson that all classes that inherit from the Node class are allowed in the lifecycle. So what classes aren't in the node class? Is it just the SceneTree class and Root class? How do they "Start" if they aren't part of the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is the base class for almost everything in GDScript, including `Node`. Although data types like `String` and `Variant` don't inherit from it.

The documentation lists a few dozen types that inherit from `Object`. Many of them, like `OS`, are available statically and "Start" at launch.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object